# How to assign a new value to a variable using a loop to make sure there is no repeated values?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that generates 4 digit numbers. Every time I want to make the variable random_val to generate a new assignment to the variable using some kind of loop so I don't get the same value printed. What is the best way to do this? Here is my code so far. This is in python btw.

```
rand1 = random.choice(numbers)
rand2 = random.choice(numbers)
rand3 = random.choice(numbers)
rand4 = random.choice(numbers)

used_numbers = []

for i in range(1, 100001):
    random_val = rand1 + rand2 + rand3 + rand4
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to get values with four digits in them range(1000, 9999) and then every time get a different value that was not previously generated to print? Also are you trying to print 100,000 times? I guess, what is the main objective of the function :)

Comment: Create list of all 4 digits number, something like `list(range(1000,9999))`, than on each iteration choose random one and delete it from list, other method would be to shuffle the list randomly and then loop over it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put all your rand variables inside of the loop. Once `random.choice` runs, it picks a semi-random number, but as soon as the function is over, the value stays the same. To refresh it every time, it needs to be inside of the loop:

```
used_numbers = []

for i in range(1, 100001):
    rand1 = random.choice(numbers)
    rand2 = random.choice(numbers)
    rand3 = random.choice(numbers)
    rand4 = random.choice(numbers)
    random_val = rand1 + rand2 + rand3 + rand4
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are overthinking, A 4 digit number is simply a number between 1000 and 10000 so you can simply do this:

```py
import random

used_num_list = []

for i in range(10001):
    four_dig_num = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    while four_dig_num in used_num_list:
        four_dig_num = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    print(four_dig_num)
    used_num_list.append(four_dig_num)
```

Comment: Ah turns out I was overthinking it a little bit. Haha, maybe not a little but, a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using a set instead of a list for `used_nums` so that membership tests run much faster, considering the loop is running 10k+ times and so there would be 10k+ elements by the end.

Comment: Think of the scenario of the last number you want to rand, and how many times your while loop is hitting.